# Ubuntu 22.04 gnome-shell --version return 40.5

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04 and I couldn't install several of my gnome extensions. After a few hours of research, I finally realized that there seems to be a gnome-shell version issue somehow.

When asking the gnome version number using the gnome-shell --version, the system returns "40.5".

[image: gnome-shell --version]

However, when looking into the Ubuntu settings About dialog the gnome version displayed is clearly 42.2.0.

[image: Ubuntu Settings About Dialog]

I eventually succeeded in making most of my extensions work by setting their supported shell version to 40.5 but I am wondering if my system upgrade had an issue and what I should do to fix it.

So I tried `apt-get install gnome-shell=42.2-0ubuntu0.2` and I got the following answer back:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libwacom2 : 
Depends: libwacom-common (= 1.8-2ubuntu2) but 2.2.0-1 is to be installed             
Recommends: libwacom-bin (= 1.8-2ubuntu2)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may have a system upgrade issue - my system also is an upgrade, but reports 42.2

Comment: Any idea what I should do to fix this ?

Comment: So I tried `apt-get install gnome-shell=42.2-0ubuntu0.2` and I got the following answer back : `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwacom2 : Depends: libwacom-common (= 1.8-2ubuntu2) but 2.2.0-1 is to be installed
             Recommends: libwacom-bin (= 1.8-2ubuntu2)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`
I'll try resolving this then and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Okay turns out my upgrade did have an issue.
I did
`apt-get install libwacom-common`
and now everything looks like it's back to normal.